# "Name not defined" in Python

Tags: python

I am new to programming and I have a problem. When i running the code, it gives an error:

> File "main.py", line 29, in
>
> ```
>      class workers:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
>   File "main.py", line 30, in workers                                                                                                                                                                                                           
>     workers = deque()                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
>  NameError: name 'deque' is not defined
> ```

This program generates a stream of events for tcp / udp, but asks to declare "deque ()" but I do not know how to do it. Code in Python:

```
    def udp_worker(port):
        start = time.time()
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        print('Begin sendding data to port %d' % port)
        retval = 0
        for i in range(0, MSG_AMOUNT):
            retval += sock.sendto(MESSAGE_BASE % (i, port, randrange(100)), (UDP_IP, port))
        print('Total amount of data sent %d in time %s' % (retval, str(time.time() - start)))
    
    def tcp_worker(port):
        start = time.time()
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((UDP_IP, UDP_BASE_PORT))
        print('Begin sendding data to port %d' % port)
        for i in range(0, MSG_AMOUNT):
            sock.sendall(MESSAGE_BASE % (i, port, randrange(100)) )
            #data = sock.recv(1024)
        sock.close()
        print('Total in time %s' % str(time.time() - start))
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            MSG_AMOUNT = int(sys.argv[1])
        if len(sys.argv) > 2:
            PROCESS = int(sys.argv[2])
    
        workers = deque()
        for i in range(0, PROCESS):
            port = UDP_BASE_PORT
            #t = threading.Thread(target = udp_worker, args = [port])   # comments this for testing tcp only
            t = threading.Thread(target = tcp_worker, args = [port])
            t.start()
            print("%s start" % t)
            workers.append(t)
        for w in workers:
            print("%s wait for join" % w)
            w.join()
```

Help please with problem.

Answer (score 4):

If deque is the Doubly Ended Queue from python you need to import it:

```
from collections import deque
```

You can add it below import sys

Comment: the same error only for " for i in range (0, PROCESS) "

Answer (score -1):

If you imported it correctly like suggested,

Apparently you have to input some content in `deque()`, such as an array or something. please see here attached:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deque-in-python/